# How to have a views function be called when the respective template is loaded?

Tags: python, django

So far, on my entirely blank django project I have created a simple template that looks as following.

test.html:

```
{% block includes %}
{{ mytext }}
{% endblock includes %}
```

to my views.py I added the following function:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
def testdex(requset, template_name="test.html"):
    args = {}
    text = "hello world"
    args['mytext'] = text
    return TemplateResponse(request, template_name, args)
```

My settings.py includes the following:

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "core/templates")

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

However, loading the template only shows me a blank page. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: you shows template `test.html` but in code you have assigned `news.html` - so you use wrong template.

Comment: @furas sorry for that mistake, I adjusted it but still don't get a display of the desired value

Comment: pt any text in HTML outside blocks to see if it really load this file

Comment: did you run it in console to see error messages? Did you get any error ?

Comment: and use `print()` in `testdex` to check if this function is earlly executed? Did you set it in `urls.py`?

Comment: you have typo `requset` in `testdex(requset` - it has to be `request` . Normally this should gives you error message in console.